# Django - Can I safely put information about is_staff in user model required fields to fetch them easily?

Tags: reactjs, django, djoser

The problem is that I've tried to fetch info about user in react and the only fields that get returned from backend are the fields that are put in the required fields:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Provide an email!')
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user


class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS =  ['name', 'is_staff']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Is it safe to do it like this or do I have to create separate api endpoint to return this information (I hope it is not necessary)?

EDIT:

serializers.py

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email','name','password')
```

And I do not have any views in views.py, probably because I am using djoser? I am kinda new to django and djoser, but I believe I should be having another serializer to fetch the data?

EDIT 2:

Settings for DJOSER:

```
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS':{
        'user_create': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    },
    'EMAIL': {
        'password_reset': 'accounts.email.CustomPasswordResetEmail',
        'password_changed_confirmation': 'accounts.email.CustomPasswordChangedConfirmationEmail',
        'activation': 'accounts.email.CustomActivationEmail',
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the view and serializer you are using to fetch the user data?

Comment: I did add the serializer

Comment: Did you add your serializer to the `DJDOSER['SERIALIZERS]` setting? https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#serializers

Comment: Edited it again

Comment: I found another way around. Can you tell me if this is better? I created a serializer: 

`class CurrentUserSerializer(UserSerializer):`
        `class Meta: model = User`
               `fields = ('id', 'email','name', 'is_staff')`

And added it as 

`'current_user': 'accounts.serializers.CurrentUserSerializer',`

to the settings.py